# Is a compact manifold with commutative fundamental group a torus?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth, closed manifold. If the universal covering of $M$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$, and the fundamental group of $M$ is $\mathbb Z^n$, can we conclude that $M$ is diffeomorphic to a torus?

Similarly, let $M$ be a closed complex manifold. If the universal covering of $M$ is $\mathbb{C}^n$, and the fundamental group of $M$ is $\mathbb Z^{2n}$, can we deduce that $M$ is biholomorphic equivalent to a complex torus?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that $M$ is a torus? Do you mean homeomorphic to the torus or diffeomorphic to the torus? This does make a difference. Your second question is even more ambiguous.

Comment: In the first question, I meant diffeomorphic, and biholomorphic equivalent in the second question.

Comment: Take the connected sum of a torus and an exotic sphere.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, there is no need to assume that the fundamental group is torsion-free since nontrivial finite groups cannot act freely on contractible manifolds. Now, to your questions: I am not sure about the complex setting. In the setting of smooth and topological manifolds one has the following.

1. Suppose that $\Sigma$ is an exotic 7-dimensional sphere. Then $M=T^7\# \Sigma$ is homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic to the torus $T^7$. See Remark on pages 8 and 9 of

*Farrell, F. Thomas; Jones, L. Edwin*, Classical aspherical manifolds. Expository lectures from the NSF-CBMS regional conference on K-theory and dynamics, held in Gainesville, Florida (USA) from January 9-14, 1989, National Science Foundation. Regional Conference Series in Mathematics, 75. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). vii, 54 p. (1990). [ZBL0729.57001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0729.57001).

At the same time, the univerdsal covering space of $M$ is diffeomorphic to ${\mathbb R}^7$.

2. If $M$ is a compact $n$-dimensional topological manifold with contractible universal covering space and abelian fundamental group, then it follows from the classification of finitely generated fundamental groups (combined with Whitehead's Theorem!) that $\pi_1(M)\cong {\mathbb Z}^n$. In particular, $M$ is homotopy-equivalent to the torus $T^n$ (by Whitehead's Theorem). What's much more difficult is that $M$ is **homeomorphic** to $T^n$. See Theorem 2.16 in the same book. (At the time of writing the book, Poincare Conjecture was open in dimension 3 and they had to exclude that dimension. But now, thanks to Perelman's theorem, the result holds in dimension 3 as well.)

**Edit.** I think, the question in the holomorphic setting should be asked separately since it has a very different answer. Here is what I know: Suppose that $M$ is a compact complex **Kahler** manifold of complex dimension $n$ whose universal covering space is contractible and $\pi_1(M)$ is abelian. Then $M$ admits a finite (unramified) holomorphic covering by a complex torus (i.e. a quotient of ${\mathbb C}^n$ by a properly discontinuous torsion-free group of complex translations). This is a consequence of Theorem 2 in

*Beauville, Arnaud*, [**Variétés kähleriennes dont la première classe de Chern est nulle**](https://doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1214438181), J. Differ. Geom. 18, 755-782 (1983). [ZBL0537.53056](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0537.53056).

It is very likely that the finite holomorphic covering can be taken to be trivial but I do not have time and energy to dig into details of Beauville's paper.